# Use a dict as a switch to update class attributes - how to insert them as references?

Tags: python, dictionary, python-3.x, switch-statement

Hi I was trying to save some typing and be "clever" by doing this...

```
class foo(object):
    def __init__()
        self.eric = 0
        self.john = 0
        self.michael = 0
        self.switchdict = {'Eric':self.eric, 'John':self.john, 'Michael':self.michael}

    def update(self, whattoupdate, value):
       if whattoupdate in self.switchdict:
           self.switchdict[whattoupdate] += value
```

After it didn't work it was obvious that the integer values were not getting passed by reference, but just as integers. I resorted to a long work-around by turning the attributes into lists but I suspect there is a better way.

I actually have about 30 of these attributes, so saving the typing and being able to add them to a list is pretty handy but my google-fu did not yield any satisfying ways to do this.

Any clever but still readable and Pythonic suggestions?

Comment: Any reason you can't just have a `dict` of name:count and access that via name - why do instance attributes need to exist?

Comment: integers are passed in exactly the same way as everything else. The difference is that integers are immutable: `i = j = 1; assert i is j; i += 1; assert i is not j and i != j`

Comment: Hey Jon - that works too, I got into this solutions by coding without paying enough attention to design :-). I do like having the attributes as they are clearer to read (to me) than the dict contents. I settled on reimplementing using setattr().

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Congratulations! You just reinvented a limited form of `setattr()`. :-)

I think you're in for a maintenance nightmare if you go far down this road, but if you insist, I'd consider something like:

```
class foo(object):
    allowedattrs = ['eric', 'john', 'michael']

    def __init__(self):
        self.eric = 0
        self.john = 0
        self.michael = 0
        self.switchdict = {'Eric':self.eric, 'John':self.john, 'Michael':self.michael}

    def update(self, whattoupdate, value):
        key = whattoupdate.lower()
        if key not in self.allowedattrs:
            raise AttributeError(whattoupdate)
        setattr(self, key, getattr(self, key) + value)

f = foo()
f.update('john', 5)
f.update('john', 4)
print f.john
```

But wouldn't it really be a lot easier to store your values in a nice `defaultdict`?

```
from collections import defaultdict

class foo(object):
    allowedattrs = ['eric', 'john', 'michael']

    def __init__(self):
        self.values = defaultdict(int)

    def update(self, whattoupdate, value):
        self.values[whattoupdate] += value

f = foo()
f.update('john', 5)
f.update('john', 4)
print f.values['john']
```

Comment: I knew there was an elegant solution but what I am not seeing here is how the allowedattrs is used... I think that the idea to use setattr() is probably a more attractive way to go. If you want to provide some guidance in that direction I'd be very appreciative :=)